# oracle datatype for multiple periods in number

Tags: plsql

I was looking if there is any NUMBER type datatype available for storing a number hierarchy like
1.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
2.0
2.0.1  etc in an Oracle table.
Is varchar2 the only option?

Comment: Problem with Varchar2 is that you cannot sort it properly. Do you have any restrictions on these numbers (such as only up to five levels with up to 3 digits)? Then you could encode it as a single integer (like 002000001000000) or in multiple colums. Also, people like to have "-RC1", "beta5" and stuff in their version numbers sometimes.

Comment: There are no restrictions on the number of digits, but it will always be numeric, will not have endings like -RC1 or beta5. I tried with the varchar2, it was sorting properly, but I don't think we can trust it always.

Comment: Re: sorting: Try sorting `9.8, 9.9, 9.9.5, 9.10, 9.11, 10.0`

Comment: Yes, I understanding the problem. Its taking character by character and sorting. Is splitting based on period the only option left?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but here's my take:

Since you're looking to combine both the **storage** of multiple bits of data (the component portions of the version number) along with **behavior** (knowing how to sort), then a user-defined type may be what you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE version_num AS OBJECT (
  major_version INTEGER,
  minor_version INTEGER,
  fix_version   INTEGER,
  ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION compare (other version_num) RETURN INTEGER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY version_num AS 
  ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION compare (other version_num) RETURN INTEGER IS
  BEGIN
    IF (self.major_version > other.major_version) THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSIF (self.major_version < other.major_version) THEN
      RETURN -1;
    ELSE
      IF (self.minor_version > other.minor_version) THEN
        RETURN 1;
      ELSIF (self.minor_version < other.minor_version) THEN
        RETURN -1;
      ELSE
        IF (self.fix_version > other.fix_version) THEN
          RETURN 1;
        ELSIF (self.fix_version < other.fix_version) THEN
          RETURN -1;
        ELSE
          RETURN 0;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END compare;
END;
/
```

First, this creates your type spec, containing (in this example) three components of your version number. The important thing to note is the `ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION`, which provides Oracle a method by which to sort your `version_num` objects.

The second section tells Oracle *how* to perform the sort. This just compares each component piece starting with the highest order, and returns `-1` if `self` is lower, `+1` if `self` is higher, or `0` if `self` is equal to `other`.

Documentation on Oracle user-defined functions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm).

---

For demonstration purposes, here's a simple use-case and test of our `version_num` object:

```
CREATE TABLE version_control (
  sys_name VARCHAR2(30),
  version  version_num
);

INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System One', version_num (9,8,0));
INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System Two', version_num (9,9,0));
INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System Three', version_num (9,9,5));
INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System Four', version_num (9,10,0));
INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System Five', version_num (9,11,0));
INSERT INTO version_control (sys_name, version)
VALUES ('System Six', version_num (10,0,0));
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM version_control v ORDER BY v.version;
```

Since we've made a user-defined type, we can use it as a datatype for our table definitions just like anything else.

This solution can be made more user-friendly with the addition of a `display_name` property on the `version_num` object, which could be generated from the other properties via a trigger. You could also implement null handling for when you don't have all three version components.